# Problems implementing clang -fno-stack-protector to compile code on Macbook Pro

Tags: c++, c, clang, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I am trying to test a buffer overflow example.

Below is my code that I am trying to compile with filename buffOVF.c :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //stack corruption
    char buf2[16] = "overwriteme";
    //slightly less than 16 bytes but it doesn't matter
    char buf1[16];
    //uninitialized

    strcpy(buf1, "1234567890123456789");
    //buffer contains 16 bytes, I've input 19 (overflow of 4 due to null ptr at end of string)
    //writing to buf1

    printf("buf1 val: %s\n", buf1);
    printf("buf2 val: %s\n", buf2);
    printf("buf1 addr: %p\n", (void *)buf1);
    printf("buf2 addr: %p\n", (void *)buf2);

    // TO RUN : gcc -o bufferOVF. bufferOVF.c -fno-stack-protector && clear && ./bufferOVF.


    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile this on a Macbook Pro with OSX 10.14 using the following command:

`clang -o buffOVF. buffOVF.c -fno-stack-protector`

Now I am attempting to run this *without* stack protection so that I can see the overflow occur. However, this does not happen as I keep getting this as my output:
`Abort trap: 6`

Why might this be happening? I've done a lot of research and I can't find anything that solves this particular issue.

Comment: "I want to see what happens when I overflow a buffer" "Program aborts due to overflow" "How can I make this stop so I can see what happens when I overflow the buffer" ???

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: lol y'all sarcastic. I am trying to implement a proof of concept. If you want to see specifically what I am doing, check out Engineer Man's video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ6pGrXY1Us. Here he does the exact same thing except can read the output of the buffers. that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Then you have employed a fundamental misunderstanding of the very nature of undefined behaviour, and indeed of an abstract programming language in the first place! If you want to code bare metal, it's time to open up your text editor and get writing some assembly. Oops, nope, the OS is still going to reel you back in... Computers specifically do not want people doing things like this, obviously!

Comment: I understand this. did you watch the video? I am simply trying to reproduce the same output. running the exact same commands he got this output:                                   buf1 val: 1234567890123456789     buf2 val: 789      do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Your previous comment shows that you do _not_ understand this! You are expecting to rely on some particular outcome of undefined behaviour. That is nonsense, folly, not going to happen. I can't really make that clearer. Don't care what some guy on YouTube says...

Comment: thanks for all the help! you really tried your best to see things from my perspective. hope you hav a great rest of your day.

Comment: Sarcasm won't help either.

Answer (score 3):

> Why might this be happening?

It's happening because, erm, *you overflowed the buffer!*

This is literally what you wanted to observe: what happens when you overflow the buffer.

Results may vary, as is always the case with undefined behaviour.

Stop overflowing the buffer.